# Why do two inline-block elements not remain on the same horizontal line?

Tags: html, css, formatting

After reading up on how to create a horizontal list (Navigation Bar), I wanted to add a header for the current page along with the navigation links on the same line. When viewing the file in a browser, the header and horizontal unordered list appear on different lines, even though they both have their display set to inline. What is the cause of this and is there an easy fix?

```css
.header {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
#nav_bar ul li, #nav_bar h1{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#nav_bar a:link, #navbar a:visited {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>myWebpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <a href="http://example.com/"><img src="example.jpg" class="header" /></a>
    <div id="nav_bar">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="foo.html">Foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="bar.html">Bar</a></li>
        <li><a href="baz.html">Baz</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the document you see that your list is not inline-block.

```css
.header {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
#nav_bar ul, #nav_bar ul li, #nav_bar h1 { /* <-------------- this */
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#nav_bar a:link, #navbar a:visited {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>myWebpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <a href="http://example.com/"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/80" class="header" /></a>
    <div id="nav_bar">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="foo.html">Foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="bar.html">Bar</a></li>
        <li><a href="baz.html">Baz</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. Is putting multiple elements in a CSS block with comma separators a good practice, or is it up to preference?

Comment: It's a useful and widely-used technique. Obviously you'd have to make adjustments to avoid the double border.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ul` is not set to inline-block. By default `ul` is a block level element so you just need to add `display:inline-block` to your `ul` too.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a float and a margin for them to align correctly.

```
#nav_bar ul li, #nav_bar h1{
float: left;
margin: 1px;
display: inline;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```